# loop the function of html parser

Tags: python, python-2.7, matlab, matlab-figure

I want to loop for the 1,2,3 which is the file name, I can run with this in script. But, I would like to do for loop at here:

```
eval('!html_parser.py 1');
eval('!html_parser.py 2');
eval('!html_parser.py 3');
```

And I get the error for this:

```
for i = 1:3

eval('!html_parser.py',strcat(int2str(i)));

end
```

[image]

html_parser.py

```
from optparse import OptionParser
p = optparse.OptionParser('%prog')
(options, args) = p.parse_args()

folder_count = args[2]

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

pattern = "*.*htm*"

captured_text = ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to build the different strings as in your first snipped, you might want to consider this

```
for i = 1:3

   eval([ '!html_parser.py ', num2str(i) ]);

end
```

Here the string is built by (implicit) concatenation of two strings.

Comment: I get the error like this "html_parser.py1' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. "

Comment: @user3340270, I forgot a space after the '.py '.
Now it should be correct.